# 'Application identity is not set' with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm scratching my head at this issue and have spent quite some time looking into it. Every question I've looked at based on this issue looks to be with debugging (I also have this issue with debugging). However, that's not the reason behind this.

In my application I gave the user the option to create a shortcut so that the application will run automatically in startup (I found this a much easier approach than editing the registry).

```
string copyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + "\\";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(copyPath + "\\" + "ZApp.url"))
{
    string app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
    writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + app);
    writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
    string icon = app.Replace('\\', '/');
    writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

This code works great. However, whenever the application checks for an update in the background, it throws the `Application identity is not set` error.

This is the code that I use for checking for an update:

```
ApplicationDeployment deploy = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment; //<- Error thrown here
UpdateCheckInfo update = deploy.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
```

Again, it works great if I start the application using the icon that [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) places on my desktop, however not great if I use the shortcut icon that my code creates in the startup folder. Is there a way for me to programmatically get round this?

Comment: Could you please validate if `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` is true, the line before the exception throws?

Comment: it returns false, when my application is deployed it is a available online or offline

Comment: Aha - I understand your problem. But I don't understand your approach. From my point of view you are using ClickOnce for something it is not designed to be used for. You may try to use mage [cmd line] of MageUI to create better "shortcut" aka. package.

Comment: Could you please add the value of `app` to the question, when creating the shortcut?

Comment: @Herdo C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\PACHCQ0A.L8Z\T1NMM6L3.GOM\zapp..tion_e31d3d465cffe92b_0001.0000_83d166c806f22115\MyApp.exe

Comment: @rudolf_franek all in all, i am trying to create a startup shortcut for my application so that it will run when windows starts, however when my application starts by that shortcut it loses the ability to check for updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deployment state is the cause of the error.
As already explained by [rudolf_franek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872496/rudolf-franek), the application is not network deployed. Applying the check before accessing the `CurrentDeployment` will make your application more safe:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    // accessing the CurrentDeployment won't throw an exception
    var deploy = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
}
```

But to resolve the problem causing the `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` being false, you should take a look at this [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/87daf27e-4184-4d0e-8b6e-54a9849459f0/isnetworkdeployed-is-false-when-executing-through-exe?prof=required).
**tl;dr:** Creating a shortcut referencing the **.exe* file will make the application run as stand-alone.

**The solution:**
You should create a proper shortcut, where you reference the application deployment manifest (a.k.a. **.application* file).
This should do the trick.

Comment: I am right in thinking that by the manifest file you are referring to the file that is in the same folder as the setup?

Comment: Yes, you are. This part seems to me to be the answer: "You should create a proper shortcut, where you reference the application deployment manifest (a.k.a. *.application file). This should do the trick."

Comment: @Andy Yes. It's deployed alongside the *\*.exe* file.

Comment: Note: ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed gives a ***first-chance exception*** when not running under ClickOnce.

Comment: @PeterMortensen [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "If you want your application to run both inside and **outside of a ClickOnce deployment* [...], test IsNetworkDeployed before accessing the CurrentDeployment property." This shouldn't happen, according to the documentation. The source of the exception is probably _not_ caused by being not ClickOnce deployed.

Comment: I have the issue described by the op AND the .IsNetworkDeployed is false after the first update has happened.  Thus every other time the update check executes, I get the "application identity not set" error.

Comment: Actually, maybe my issue is the way that the application is restarted.System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
                            Application.Exit(); rather than Application.Restart();

Comment: @Ads Why would you use `Application.Exit()`, `Process.Start()` and `Application.Restart()`?

Comment: @Herdo, I said .start(), .exit() rather than .restart(). I'm not using all three at once.